# Number of images

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction

[image]

> A glass slab of refractive index n=2 has left spherical of radius 10cm and right surface plane.From both surfaces refraction as well as reflection takes place.A point of object P is placed at a distance 15cm from point O1.

My approach:
I could think of three cases

(1 ) First the object P will get refracted directly from the left spherical surface .Image no 1

(2) The object P will get reflected from the right surface plane.
Image no 2

(3) The object P will get reflected from the left spherical surface and then refracted at the normal plane.Image no 3

So I am getting 3 images which is not in any of the options....Could you tell me why one of my solutions is not possible ?

Comment: I don't get how you explain the 3rd image. Do you meant to say it will be 'reflected' at the left spherical surface and then 'refracted at the plane surface?

Comment: @SmarthBansal yes

Comment: This image won't be visible to observer E1

Comment: @SmarthBansal why

Comment: A person can see the image if rays of light hit the eye. The rays after reflection never reach the first observer

Comment: @SmarthBansal can you elaborate this in an answer....will help me a lot

Comment: I provided an answer below, will be pleased to clarify further doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note-* We will be considering the time duration from when the light starts off from the object. This does not mean that the light ray did not exist before that or was emitted by the object.

**First image:**
The light rays start off at the object; Hits the spherical surface; Some of it gets refracted; and reach into the first observer's eyes. The second observer cannot see this image as the rays don't enter his eyes.

**Second image:**
The light rays start off at the object; Hit the plane surface; Some of it reflects back into the same medium; Hits the spherical surface; Some of it get refracted;  and reach into the first observer's eyes. The second observer cannot see this image as the rays don't enter his eyes.

**Second image:**
The light rays start off at the object; Hits the spherical surface;  Some of it reflects back into the same medium.; Hits the plane surface; Some of it refracts  and reaches the second observer. The first observer cannot see this image as it doesn't enter his eye.

*Note*- This back and forth reflection and refraction could be done infinitely many times and both the observers would see infinite images;

- It would depend upon the actual values of the distances and the refractive indexes.
- The intensity would reduce. And in-case of infinite images (which is quite common). For all such purposes we consider the images formed by first two reflections/refractions. Although this is no accurate, it does give the an idea under normal conditions.

Comment: Never knew the question was asking this in such a detail.I will think about this and get back to you later